# Как сделать на qml - qt фиксированный размер окна?

Tags: windows, qt, qml

Знаю что делается это с помощью флагов, но никак не пойму верный синтаксис в qml:

```
Window {
...
flags: "Qt::CustomizeWindowHint", "Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint"...
...
}
```

На данный момент такой вариант, не дает нужного результата (принимается только первый флаг) Варианты с флагами в одних кавычках тоже не прошли.

Флаг  `MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint` не радует, так как блокирует перемещения окна (он так и должен делать?)

Помогите примером как правильно выставить флаги и зафиксировать размер окна.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может есть какой-то «мудрый» способ, который я не знаю, но Вашу проблему можно решить так:

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 360
    height: 360
    maximumHeight: height
    maximumWidth: width
    minimumHeight: height
    minimumWidth: width
}
```

---

Чтобы убрать кнопки сворачивания и разворачивания, можно использовать следующую комбинацию флагов:

```
flags: Qt.Window | Qt.CustomizeWindowHint | Qt.WindowTitleHint | Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint | Qt.WindowSystemMenuHint
```

Comment: Простите, не могу прямо сейчас попробовать - а кнопку развернуть это скрывает и пункт "развернуть" в меню?

Comment: @Mira, нет, кнопки остаются, но размер окна не меняют. Кнопок не должно быть?

Comment: Завтра узнаю можно ли кнопку оставить ) @ixSci спасибо большое, очень меня выручаете :)

Comment: @Mira, добавил комбинацию флагов, чтобы убрать кнопки.

Comment: А... Вот оно как :) через точку и трубу :) просто в документации очень кратко - что есть такое свойство. И все, ссылка на c++ синтаксис флагов, догадайся сам как оно в qml  :)

Comment: @Mira, в QML работает JavaScript, поэтому если что, нужно смотреть документацию по JavaScript